# EEVEE scene illuminated but no lights present in Render view

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I found a Tutorial by Blender Guru on Youtube, on doing architectural renders in EEVEE, so thought I'd give it a go.

For some reason, when I switch to render view, everything is illuminated, so adding lamps as he does in the tutorial doesn't have any effect.

Am I missing something simple? Even if I add a light it has no effect on the objects in the scene. (this is illustrated in the attached images.

The room is a cube with a solidify modifier added and a boolean modifier to create the window. The boolean object is set to bounds (all as in the tutorial.) Any Ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Simon
[image]
[image]

---

Here's the second one showing the lights not affecting objects

Also makes no difference if materials are added or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!!

When I'd saved my own start up preferences, Id forgotten to delete a lighting Cache. I deleted it, re added my lamp and everything works again. Stupid error on my part